# Store socketId session for sending private messages using Sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

Im building a chat app and im also trying to implement private messaging functionality. Actually each user registers and logs in the app with their credentials so i guess this is where i should be storing maybe the socketId in the user session in order to access each client with the same id no matter a page refresh occurs. I have seen some examples in previous version of sails like https://github.com/balderdashy/sailsChat and they all seem to use the onConnect function in config/sockets.js. Then you can send messages to a specific user using something like User.message(id, data) but this have been changed in sails 0.11 and now is beforeConnect which is kinda confusing. If anyone can point me out in the right direction for this i would be appreciated.